# How to find sequence lengths in a fasta file?

Tags: python, list, character, bioinformatics, fasta

I am currently working with a `fasta` file (a text file) that has a list of DNA extraction sequences (contigs), each with a header followed by lines of nucleotides, which is the nucleotide length of that contig. there are 120 contigs, with each entry marked by a line that starts with ">" to denote the sequence information. after this line, a length of nucleotides of that sequence is given.

example:

```
>gi|571136972|ref|XM_006625214.1| Plasmodium chabaudi chabaudi small subunit ribosomal protein 5 (Rps5) (rps5) mRNA, complete cds
ATGAGAAATATTTTATTAAAGAAAAAATTATATAATAGTAAAAATATTTATATTTTATATTATATTTTAATAATATTTAAAAGTATTTTTATTATTTTATTTAATAGTAAATATAATGTGAATTATTATTTATATAATAAAATTTATAATTTATTTATTATATATATAAAATTATATTATATTATAAATAATATATATTATAATAATAATTATTATTATATATATAATATGAATTATATA
TATTTTTATATTTATAAATATAATAGTTTAAATAATA
>gi|571136996|ref|XM_006625226.1| Plasmodium chabaudi chabaudi small subunit ribosomal protein 2 (Rps2) (rps2) mRNA, complete cds
ATGTTTATTACATTTAAAGATTTATTAAAATCTAAAATATATATAGGAAATAATTATAAAAATATTTATATTAATAATTATAAATTTATATATAAAATAAAATATAATTATTGTATTTTAAATTTTACATTAATTATATTATATTTATATAAATTATATTTATATATTTATAATATATCTATATTTAATAATAAAATTTTATTTATTATTAATAATAATTTAATTACAAATTTAATTATT
AATATATGTAATTTAACTAATAATTTTTATATTATTA
```

what I would like to do is make a list of every contig. My problem is, I do not know the syntax needed to tell Python to:

1. find the line after the line that starts with ">"
2. take a count of all of the characters in the lines of that sequence
3. return a value to a list of all contig values (a list that gives a list of length of every contig, ie 126, 300, 25...)
4. make sure the last contig (which has no ">" to denote its end) is counted.

I would like a list of integers, so that I can calculate things like the mean length of the contigs, standard deviation, cool gene equations etc.

Comment: Well you should post what you have actually tried. asking someone to write a program for you is not what SO is for

Comment: this is a second part to a program in which I am building. I'm sorry for presenting myself as someone who wished to have the code written. I simply don't know where to begin. currently, my code so far is

import re

with open("COPYFORTESTINGplastid.1.rna.fna") as fasta:
 contigs = 0
 total_characters = 0
 for line in fasta:
  if line.strip().startswith('>'):
   contigs = contigs  + 1
   #print contigs (this is good if you want a list of every instance, ie 1-120)
 print "The total number of contigs: %s." %contigs
  if line.strip().startswith('>') = False:
   str = line

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use biopython as Martin has suggested.  Here's a start for you that will print the sequence ID and length to terminal.  You can install biopython with pip, i.e. `pip install biopython`

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

FileIn = sys.argv[1]

handle = open(FileIn, 'rU')
SeqRecords = SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')
for record in SeqRecords:   #loop through each fasta entry
   length = len(record.seq)    #get sequence length
   print "%s: %i bp" % (record.id, length)     #print sequence ID: seq length
```

Or you could store the results in a dictionary:

```
handle = open(FileIn, 'rU')
sequence_lengths = {}
SeqRecords = SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')
for record in SeqRecords:   #loop through each fasta entry
    length = len(record.seq)    #get sequence length
    sequence_lengths[record.id] = length

#access dictionary outside of loop
print sequence_lengths
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you: it prints the number of ACGT's in the lines that follow a line that includes `>`:

```
import re

with open("input.txt") as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()

data = re.split(r">.*", data)[1:]

data = [sum(1 for ch in datum if ch in 'ACGT') for datum in data]

print(data)
```

Comment: this has worked for me, and I have incorporated it into my program, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. I have looked at the biopython stuff and am excited to understand it and incorporate it. The overall goal of this assignment was to teach me how to understand python, rather than finding the solution outright, or at least if I find the solution, I have to be able to explain it in my own words.

Anyway, I have created a code incorporating that element as well as others. I have a few more things to do, and if I am confused, I will return to ask.

here is my first working code outside of working directly with my supervisor or tutorials that I made and understand (woo!):

```
import re

with open("COPYFORTESTINGplastid.1.rna.fna") as fasta:
    contigs = 0
    for line in fasta:
        if line.strip().startswith('>'):
            contigs = contigs  + 1
with open("COPYFORTESTINGplastid.1.rna.fna") as fasta:
    data = fasta.read()
    data = re.split(r">.*", data)[1:]
    data = [sum(1 for ch in datum if ch in 'ACGT') for datum in data]
print "Total number of contigs: %s" %contigs
total_contigs = sum(data)
N50 = sum(data)/2
print "number used to determine N50 = %s" %N50
average = 0
total = 0
for n in data:
    total = total + n
mean = total / len(data)
print "mean length of contigs: %s" %mean
print "total nucleotides in fasta = %s" %total_contigs
#print "list of contigs by length: %s" %sorted([data])
l = data
l.sort(reverse = True)
print "list of contigs by length: %s" %l
```

this does what I want it to do, but if you have any comments or advice, I would love to hear.

next up, determining N50 with this sweet sweet list. thanks again!

Comment: Code reviews aren't really the purpose of Stackoverflow, but if you post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I'll give you my remarks on your code there.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to calculate N50 and it seemed to work nicely. I can parse the command line and run any .fa file through the program

```
def calc_n50(array):
     array.sort(reverse = True)
     n50 = 0 #sums lengths
     n = 0 #n50 sequence
     half = sum(array)/2
     for val in array:
         n50 += val
         if n50 >= half:
             n = val
             break #breaks loop when condition is met
 print "N50 is",n
```